# Double factorial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, factorial, closed-form

My question is pretty simple.

Since $n! \gt n!!$, it's clear by the comparison test that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {1}{n!!}$ converges.

> But what value does the sum converge to? How does one go about determining its value (if possible)?

Comment: See [line (23)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) for a closed form.

Comment: A quick note: $n!>n!!$ does not imply $\sum_n(n!!)^{-1}$ converges (inverting flips the inequality). However, $n!!>2^{n/2}$ for large enough $n$, so convergence may be deduced by comparison with $\sum_n2^{-n/2}$.

Comment: The inequality $n!\gt n$ is also clear, but $\sum{1\over n}$ does *not* converge.

Answer (score 11):

What is $n!!$ ? For $n=2k$, we have
$$ (2k)!! = 2k(2k-2)(2k-4)\dotsm (2), $$
which it is easy to see is
$$ 2^k k!. $$
Therefore the even sum is easy:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k)!!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}2^{-k} = e^{1/2}. $$
What about the odd terms?
$$ (2k+1)!! = (2k+1)(2k-1)\dotsm 3 \cdot 1 = \frac{(2k+1)!}{2^k k!} $$
This can be shown, by [a fairly nasty process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) that I'll spare you, to be the following:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!!} = e^{x^2/2} \int_0^x e^{-t^2/2} \, dt. $$
After substituting $x=1$, you can't really get it into a more closed form than that (this is the same as the integral of the normal distribution's density function, which is well-known to not be expressible in closed form).

So
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!!} = \sqrt{e} \left( 1 + \int_0^1 e^{-t^2/2} \, dt \right). $$

Comment: +1 for a mathematically legitimate reason to write !!? (and for a nice answer, of course)

Comment: I felt compelled to put a space in there: $n!!$? just felt silly...

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add that the "nasty process" mentioned by Chappers is indeed not that nasty. You can take $\varphi(x)=\mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}\int_0^x\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}t$ which is a differentiable function whose derivative equals $2x\varphi(x)+1$, so it is actually a $C^\infty$ function. Then, by applying Leibniz' rule we can see that the odd order derivatives of $\varphi$ satisfy $$\varphi^{(2k+1)}(x)=2x\varphi^{(2k)}(x)+2k\varphi^{(2k-1)}(x)$$ from where $\varphi^{(2k+1)}(0)=2^kk!=(2k)!!$. Furthermore, since $\varphi$ is an odd function, its even order derivatives all vanish at $0$ and so $$\varphi(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!}x^k.$$ Since $(2k+1)!!(2k)!!=(2k+1)!$ we can conclude the equality.