# Closed-from for the series: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k!)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, factorial, closed-form

As the title says, I'm wondering whether there is any known closed-from for the following series:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k!)!}$$

Here I don't mean the double factorial (treated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482211/)) when I'm writing $(k!)!$, but the factorial of the integer $k!$.

Trying on [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B10%7D%201%2F%28k!%29!), I get the funny value $2.501388888888888888888890500626459...$, but [no closed-form](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Binfty%7D+1%2F%28k!%29!).
If you have any reference which focuses on this number, I would also be interested. I found nothing so far.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The fifth term is about $1.6 * 10^{-24}$ and the sixth term is much smaller than $10^{-133}$. Fast convergence indeed. :D

Comment: It's highly unlikely, for a slightly curious reason: this number is not just transcendental but a form of [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number), and such highly approximable numbers tend not to be 'natural' - most of the numbers that we come across on a regular basis have (or are strongly believed to have) finite irrationality measure.

Comment: $\sum_{k\geq0}1/(k!)!\approx\sum_{k=0}^{3} 1/(k!)!=1801/720=2.5013\bar{8}$

Comment: https://oeis.org/A336686